# I want to replicate an existing record for a new employee ID

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I want to replicate an existing employees record for a new employee.
EG.

If my present employee details are:

```
EmpID: 100
EmpDept: Accounts
EmpEndDate: 12-12-2018
```

So when I am adding a new employee I dont want to manually write an insert statement, all I want is a procedure that can replicate all the other values present for the new employee.

Comment: insert into employees_table(EmpDept, EmpEndDate) select EmpDept, EmpEndDate from employees_table where EmpId = 100

Comment: Very odd requirement. Why bother inserting same data over and over again, for different persons? At least you want a new EmpID and new start and end dates. And perhaps different names?

Comment: I wonder why employee id is not primary key?

Comment: default values?

Comment: The scenario is that only empID will be different as it will be a new user, the remaining fields will be same as the existing records user whose records we were suppose to replicate in order to give similar access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to increment the max `EmpID` by 1 so as to maintain uniqueness of rows -  with a `CONNECT BY LOOP`, if you want multiple rows.

```
INSERT INTO Employee (
    EmpID
    ,EmpDept
    ,EmpEndDate
    )
WITH m(max_id) AS (
        SELECT MAX(EmpID)
        FROM Employee
        )
SELECT max_id + LEVEL
    ,EmpDept
    ,EmpEndDate
FROM Employee
CROSS JOIN m
WHERE EmpID = p_emp_id CONNECT BY LEVEL <= p_numof_rows;
```

Put this query in a procedure and pass `p_emp_id`  and  `p_numof_rows` as parameter to replicate as many rows as you want. Hopefully you have one row currently in the table for each `p_emp_id` you would pass.

If you always want a single row, just use `max_id + 1` and remove `CONNECT BY LEVEL <= p_numof_rows`

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7d467/1)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a sequence named `Employees__EmpID__Seq` to generate the unique employee IDs then:

```
INSERT INTO Employees ( EmpID, EmpDept, EmpEndDate )
  SELECT Employees__EmpID__Seq.NEXTVAL,
         EmpDept,
         EmpEndDate
  FROM   Employees
  WHERE  EmpID = :id_of_the_employee_you_want_to_copy;
```

You can then run that statement and it will copy an existing record.

> all I want is a procedure that can replicate all the other values present for the new employee.

If you really need to wrap it in a procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE copy_employee(
  i_empid IN  Employees.EmpID%TYPE,
  o_empid OUT Employees.EmpID%TYPE
)
IS
BEGIN
  o_empid := Employees__EmpID__Seq.NEXTVAL;

  INSERT INTO Employees ( EmpID, EmpDept, EmpEndDate )
    SELECT o_empid,
           EmpDept,
           EmpEndDate
    FROM   Employees
    WHERE  EmpID = i_empid;

  IF SQL%ROWCOUNT <> 1 THEN
    o_empid := NULL;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/50525/1)

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it in PL/SQL,

```
DECLARE
    v_emp_rec employee%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT *
      INTO v_emp_rec
      FROM employee
     WHERE emp_id = 'emp_id_to_replicate';

    v_emp_rec.emp_id := '101';
    v_emp_rec.first_name := 'Alfie';

    INSERT INTO employee
    VALUES
    v_emp_rec;


    v_emp_rec.emp_id := '102';
    v_emp_rec.first_name := 'Alf';

    INSERT INTO employee
    VALUES
    v_emp_rec;
END;
/


COMMIT;
```